# how to transform HTML back to JSON

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, handlebars.js

I have a page where the actual container is retrieved as JSON and transformed into HTML using handlebar javascript.

The user has an option to alter the fields that are in the container. Like move around the text box which are displayed in the container. They can save these preference. They can also add new fields from the tool box provided. (imagine like a MS paint)

When the user selects to save i need to send the updated infomration back to server and save them.

In order to accomplish this, i am trying to make use of the initial JSON which was used to construct the container so that i can spend less time in building the JSON request for post.

is there a better way to transform the HTML back to JSON or should i walk through Each node/children to get the updated values and construct JSON.

Need your suggestion as i have not done these before.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I would first try updating the json in real-time as the user is modifying the html rather than trying to re-build it from scratch after.

Comment: I also need to accomodate the user adding new fields.

Comment: My suggestion applies to that as well.

Comment: Actually i was thinking would it not cause delay or user smooth interaction when i try to update frequently?

Comment: I doubt it would have any effect on the user experience. Without trying there's no way of knowing for sure though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider using [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) or any other MVVM framework to perform this 2 way bindings

With angular you can do thins like:

```
  <p>First name: {{JsonObject.firstName}}</p>
```

and if it is an input value or update this will reflect automatically back to your JSON Object.

Here is a great intro video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM